# propertiesfactorybean vs propertyplaceholderconfigurer spring?

Tags: java, spring

spring has two ways to load property files using either **propertiesfactorybean** or **propertyplaceholderconfigurer**.

Could u please explain the difference between them and when to use what?

Thanks!

Answer (score 28):

`PropertiesFactoryBean` is a `FactoryBean` implementation which reads a properties file and exposes that as an `Properties` object in the applicationcontext.

`PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer` is a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` implementation that reads a property file and uses that property file to replace placeholder variables (${somename}) with actual values. The read properties aren't available as a `Properties` object.